# Como adicionar uma extensão de arquivo na lista de extensões suportadas pelo Brackets da Adobe?

Tags: editor-de-texto, configuração

Eu estou usando os arquivos com *extensão html.eco* no meu projeto WEB e eu estou tentando editar no Adobe Brackets, mas não consigo especificar que ele deva tratar estes arquivos como fontes HTML. Eu gostaria que o Brackets me fornecesse as funcionalidades típicas de arquivo HTML (como colorir o fonte, identificar as tags na gramática, etc.)

Na verdade eu observei que isto é possível quando se altera o arquivo languages.json, porém eu estou usando a versão binária e não fiz o build a partir dos fontes.

https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/src/language/languages.json

Gostaria apenas de alterar algum arquivo de propriedade ou configuração do Brackets para conseguir editar meus arquivos .html.eco de forma que ele entenda que se trata de **mime-type text/html**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é propriamente o que eu esperava mas descobri que posso criar uma extensão simples pro Brackets da seguinte forma:

**arquivo main.js**

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    var LanguageManager = brackets.getModule("language/LanguageManager");
    var language = LanguageManager.getLanguage("html");
    language.addFileExtension("html.eco");
});
```

No Brackets, usar o menu: **Help > Show Extensions Folder**

Criar um novo folder debaixo de user, e colocar lá o arquivo main.js

Mo MAC OS X este diretório é `~/Library/Application Support/Brackets/extensions`

Reiniciar o Brackets

Para facilitar criei esta extensão trivial e disponibilizei no GITHUB. Para instalar faça o seguinte:

1. Selecione o item de menu **File > Extension Manager... / Install from URL... **  no Brackets
2. Preencha o campo URL com `https://github.com/joao-parana/add-file-extension`  e clique no botão **Install**

A extensão é habilitada automáticamente.

Espero que ajude a galera. Acredito que esta funcionalidade seja implementada no Brackets em uma versão futura pois seria uma solução mais simples para quem queira apenas instalar e usar o Brackets.

Answer (score 2):

1. Abra o arquivo: `Brackets\www\editor\EditorUtils.js`
2. Acrescente a extensão correspondente dentro do `switch (ext)`

Por exemplo:

```js
 switch (ext) {
    ...
    case "eco":
        return "htmlmixed";
    ...
```

Fonte: http://zsitro.com/how-to-extend-adobe-brackets-language-support-based-on-file-extension/

---

Pesquisando mais, encontrei as definições das linguagens suportadas em [`language/languages.json`](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/src/language/languages.json) no código atual do Brackets:

```js
"html": {
    "name": "HTML",
    "mode": ["htmlmixed", "text/x-brackets-html"],
    "fileExtensions": ["html", "htm", "shtm", "shtml", "xhtml", "cfm", "cfml", "cfc", "dhtml", "xht", "tpl", "twig", "hbs", "handlebars", "kit", "jsp", "aspx", "asp", "master","cshtml","vbhtml"],
    "blockComment": ["<!--", "-->"]
},
```

E através do [`LanguageManager`](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/blob/master/src/language/LanguageManager.js) podemos acrescentar uma nova extensão à lista, dinamicamente:

```js
var language = LanguageManager.getLanguage('html');
LanguageManager.addFileExtension('eco');
```

Ainda resta saber agora onde exatamente fazer este código rodar - se precisa de um "plugin" só para isso (evitando build dos fontes), ou se de outro modo.

Comment: @JBruni na versão do Brackets do MAC OS X não existe o arquivo EditorUtils.js e não tenho Windows aqui para testar. Você tem certeza que esta abordagem funciona na versão binária (Instalada) do Brackets sem que eu tenha que fazer o build dos fontes ?

Comment: Investiguei mais um pouco e atualizei a resposta. Estamos chegando lá...

Comment: oi @j-bruni, obrigado pela ajuda. Qualquer novidade serei grato.